# Show a PHP login page before desktop appears just after successfully login through active directory

Tags: php, authentication

I am going to make a php application system for cyber library. when an user will successfully log in through active directory then he will get an another php log in page for activate his card number before appearing the desktop. After successfully log in through php log in page then the user will get the desktop to access the browser with a time limit.

would anyone please help me that from where I can start.

Comment: Please be more clear. You cant deny access to Desktop with PHP code.

Comment: The page can be wrote in PHP but you are looking more for a VB script or .NET to make your page even come up after login.

Comment: After successfully login through active directory, the desktop will come for 1 second and then will redirect to a php login page for card user name and password and this login page will remain only for 90 seconds. if anyone fail to login within 90 seconds then this will redirect to active directory again. After this successfully login the user will get desktop screen for using the computer with a time limit. @wishchaser

Comment: First, tell me one thing. Where is all this happening? In a PC in your library(or your place) or a PC that that a user owns? Either way, if you want to force a user to login with his with his card number to access the desktop, you must have a program written with languages like Visual Basic, .NET, C#, etc..